# Regression programming using plsql for getting perfect match

Tags: oracle, plsql, match, regression, subset-sum

I am working on a function to get a perfect match out of a set of numbers (Min value is 1 and Max Value is 25).

I have given below DDL to create the table and also the insert statements and the code which I am working on currently which has got performance issues.

Run the below code.

This will run in 2 minutes if the number of records is 20.

Total records I have given here are 33, so it will take a lot of time, not sure if it gets completed.

Any inputs will be of great help.

```
CREATE TABLE xx_perfect_combi_test
(
  trx_id  NUMBER
 ,trx_val NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051303, 25);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051304, 25);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051305, 25);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051306, 24);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051307, 24);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051308, 24);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051309, 24);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051310, 23);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051311, 23);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051312, 23);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051313, 22);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051314, 22);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051315, 21);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051316, 21);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051317, 21);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051318, 20);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051319, 20);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051320, 20);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051321, 20);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051322, 18);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051323, 17);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051324, 11);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051325, 9);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051326, 8);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051327, 6);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051328, 6);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051329, 4);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051330, 3);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051331, 1);
INSERT INTO xx_perfect_combi_test (trx_id, trx_val) VALUES (2051332, 1);

COMMIT;
```

My program:

```
DECLARE
  ln_total_sum       NUMBER := 315;
  ln_orig_diff       NUMBER := ln_total_sum;
  ln_curr_diff       NUMBER;

  lv_trx_ids         VARCHAR2 (4000);
  lv_trx_ids_buff    VARCHAR2 (4000);

  lv_dummy_return    VARCHAR2 (4000);

  FUNCTION perfect_combo (p_curr_sum     IN NUMBER
                         ,p_curr_vals    IN VARCHAR2
                         ,p_rownumber    IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    lv_buf_trx_id    VARCHAR2 (4000);
  BEGIN
    FOR c1 IN (SELECT   *
               FROM (SELECT stg2.*
                           ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY stg2.trx_val DESC) AS rownumber1
                     FROM xx_perfect_combi_test stg2)
                     WHERE rownumber1 > p_rownumber
                     ORDER BY trx_val DESC) LOOP
      --dbms_output.put_line ('p_curr_sum: ' || p_curr_sum);
      --dbms_output.put_line ('p_curr_vals: ' || p_curr_vals);
      --dbms_output.put_line ('p_rownumber: ' || p_rownumber);
      --dbms_output.put_line ('---------------------------------------------------');

      IF ( (p_curr_sum + c1.trx_val) = ln_total_sum)
      THEN
        lv_buf_trx_id  := p_curr_vals;
        lv_buf_trx_id  := lv_buf_trx_id || c1.trx_id || ';';
        lv_trx_ids     := lv_buf_trx_id;
        RETURN lv_trx_ids;
      ELSIF (p_curr_sum + c1.trx_val) > ln_total_sum
      THEN
        ln_curr_diff  := ln_total_sum - p_curr_sum;

        IF ln_curr_diff < ln_orig_diff
        THEN
          ln_orig_diff     := ln_curr_diff;
          lv_trx_ids_buff  := p_curr_vals;
        END IF;

        CONTINUE;
      ELSIF (p_curr_sum + c1.trx_val) < ln_total_sum
      THEN
        ln_curr_diff     := ln_total_sum - (p_curr_sum + c1.trx_val);

        lv_buf_trx_id    := p_curr_vals;
        lv_buf_trx_id    := lv_buf_trx_id || c1.trx_id || ';';

        IF ln_curr_diff < ln_orig_diff
        THEN
          ln_orig_diff     := ln_curr_diff;
          lv_trx_ids_buff  := lv_buf_trx_id;
        END IF;

        lv_dummy_return  := perfect_combo ( (p_curr_sum + c1.trx_val), lv_buf_trx_id, c1.rownumber1);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN NULL;
  END perfect_combo;
BEGIN
  lv_dummy_return  := perfect_combo (0, NULL, 0);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('lv_trx_ids: ' || lv_trx_ids);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('lv_trx_ids_buff: ' || lv_trx_ids_buff);
END;
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on what this code is doing?

Comment: Hi Jon, This code will get set of numbers which sum up to the total. For example in the above example total is 315 so it will get the numbers which sum up to 315 or the closest match which sum up to 315

Comment: Since you're looking for a closest match, and not necessarily a perfect sum, would this be a knapsack problem instead?

Comment: Hi Job, I am looking for both if a perfect match is not found I want the program to return the closest match as well. This is not a knapsack problem because in knapsack we need both combination and optimization as well. For my scenario, only combination is enough. So the complexity is not as much as a knapsack. For now I am able to achieve this for upto 140 elements. If the count of elements is increasing it is taking long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to exit the function call completely after a match is found. I have created a global variable and checked if match is found then return completely from the function calls. This way the program is completed quickly.